# PayPal Payments Pro - Skip IPN

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

Is it possible to tell PayPal through the NVP to not send a response to the IPN handler?  For instance I use the IPN for payments I receive through a store I have running FoxyCart.  However the store Im setting up now doesnt use a 3rd party cart, Im just using the API response to handle handle everything.  Because of this I dont want PayPal to send a response to the IPN.

Ive scoped out the notify_url param, but that appears to only change where the IPN response is sent to.

I would prefer for this store that no IPN response gets sent at all, while allowing the other store to continue using the IPN it has always been.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your account settings.

There are two types of IPN's,  one is set at account level, and it's triggered whenever money comes into your account, regardless of the source. If you disable this, you will not get ny IPN's from either store.

The other type of IPN, is based on the API call being made. 
You need to check your magento payment module config to see if it's generating the second type, and disable it there.  If it's already disabled, it means that you are only getting the first type of IPN.  If this is the case, you would actually need to modify your OTHER shopping cart.

(A simpler option might be to open a child paypal account, rather than mess with all the carts)

Comment: Thank-you, I was afraid of this.  The IPN is actually set at the account level.  For a temporary fix, I have edited the original IPN handling script to ignore anything from PayPal relating to the new store.  I will have to look into the child accounts.  I wasnt aware those existed.

Comment: Just to tidy this question up:

If you specify a notify_url parameter, it over-rides the ipn listed in your PayPal profile.  

There is however no way to disregard the ipn all-together if it is set in your profile.  In other words, if it is set in your profile, you have to use either the default ipn, or the new one specified through the notify_url parameter.

Comment: One trick that I've used is to append a parameter to the URL to indicate the source.
notify_url = "http://www.site.com/ipnListener.php?source=site1"

The listener has some intelligence built in to determine which site originated the transaction